# Find + replace content of an element without losing events

Tags: javascript, events, replace

I have a function that reads the content of an element, replaces a word with a link and then rewrites the content back into the element. Obviously this means that all events that were previously set are lost.

Does anyone know of a function/method that could find and replace the content of an element without losing the events?

**Edit: Without using a library**

Here is my current code that does not destroy the events but turns `<`, for example, into `&lt;`, so I can not append HTML. This is the closest I have got:

```
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
```

My original code worked but got rid of the events:

```
element.innerHTML += content;
```

Comment: What about wrapping the section that contains replaceable text with a separate tag and isolate it from the surrounding elements that need their events preserved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/) you could do it with the [**text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method

```
var str = $('#element-id').text();
str = yourReplaceFunction(str);
$('#element-id').text(str);
```

---

**Edit:**

Another option would the [**innerHTML**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) property. It's not very elegant but works nevertheless.

```
var strElem = document.getElementById('element-id');
var str = strElem.innerHTML;
str = yourReplaceFunction(str);
strElem.innerHTML = str;
```

---

**Edit2:**

Yet another option would be to wrap the text you want to replace inside of a separate tag, for example `<span>`.

```
<div id="container">
   <a id="link-with-events">Link</a>
   <span id="replaceable">The Text Gets Replaced</span>
   <a id="more-links-with-events">Another Link</a>
</div>
```

Then you'd simply access and replace the contents of the span tag, leaving the surrounding elements untouched.

Comment: Well the problem is that I am writing a library so I don't want to be using jQuery, so do you know of any methods of find + replace that do not involve destroying the event listeners?

Comment: Do you mean the events on the containing element? Or are you referring to events defined inside the content to be replaced?

Comment: I don't see what's so inelegant with using the `innerHTML` property.

Comment: I am currently using the innerHTML property, this is what destroys the events. I need to use DOM functions but I can't find one that would let me find and replace.

Comment: @Yi Jiang: DOM is basically a tree so using tree operations makes more sense than "batch mode". But of course, that's not cast in stone, simply something I prefer.

Comment: Your third idea is the most useful. I think I am going to have to settle with that. Thanks for you time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the tag contains just text (and not additional tags):

```
element.firstChild.nodeValue=content;
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/ubj6hte4/